# How to visualize multiple bar plots in one (or splitted) pdf

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm using the `tidyverse`-`ggplot2` combination to plot multiple bar plots. In one of my comparisons i would like to have even up to 300 single plots. I was wondering if there is a possibility to make sure that the plots will be visible in the pdf file and not look like the attached example[image: bar-plots]

If possible I would prefer to have all the plots in one single pdf file, but if not, also multiple pages will be ok.

The command to plot the bar charts is

```
common %>%
  as_tibble(rownames="gene") %>% 
  left_join(x= ., y = up[,1:2], by = c("gene" = "ensembl_gene_id") ) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("S"), names_to="sample", values_to="counts") %>%
  left_join(groups, by="sample") %>%
  group_by(mgi_symbol, group, cond, time) %>%
  summarize(mean_count=mean(counts)) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = time, y = mean_count, fill=cond)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width=0.9) ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkblue", "lightblue", "black")) +
  facet_wrap(~mgi_symbol, scales = "free", ncol = 5) +
  theme_bw()
```

I forgot to add the group table

```
groups <- tibble(
  sample= colnames(normCounts),
  group = rep(seq(1, ncol(normCounts)/3), each=3),
  cond  = rep(c("WT", "GCN2-KO", "GCN1-KO"), each = 12),
  time  = rep(rep(c("0h", "1h", "4h", "8h"), each=3), times = 3 )
)
```

thanks

Adding the command with the group_map was as such

```
common %>%
  as_tibble(rownames="gene") %>% 
  left_join(x= ., y = up[,1:2], by = c("gene" = "ensembl_gene_id") ) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("S"), names_to="sample", values_to="counts") %>%
  left_join(groups, by="sample") %>%
  group_by(mgi_symbol, group, cond, time) %>%
  summarize(mean_count=mean(counts)) %>%
  group_map(function(g, ...)
  ggplot(g, aes(x = time, y = mean_count, fill=cond)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width=0.9) ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkblue", "lightblue", "black")) +
  facet_wrap(~mgi_symbol, scales = "free", ncol = 5) +
  theme_bw()
  )
```

EDIT

This is how the data looks like in the input table (after summarizing the means)

```
df <-
  common %>%
  as_tibble(rownames="gene") %>% 
  left_join(x= ., y = up[,1:2], by = c("gene" = "ensembl_gene_id") ) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("S"), names_to="sample", values_to="counts") %>%
  left_join(groups, by="sample") %>%
  group_by(mgi_symbol, group, cond, time) %>%
  summarize(mean_count=mean(counts)) %>%
  ungroup()
df
#>`summarise()` regrouping output by 'mgi_symbol', 'group', 'cond' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 1,212 x 5
#>    mgi_symbol    group cond    time  mean_count
#>    <chr>         <int> <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>
#>  1 0610031O16Rik     1 WT      0h          14.4
#>  2 0610031O16Rik     2 WT      1h          30.9
#>  3 0610031O16Rik     3 WT      4h          45.5
#>  4 0610031O16Rik     4 WT      8h          56.0
#>  5 0610031O16Rik     5 GCN2-KO 0h          18.9
#>  6 0610031O16Rik     6 GCN2-KO 1h          39.4
#>  7 0610031O16Rik     7 GCN2-KO 4h          13.9
#>  8 0610031O16Rik     8 GCN2-KO 8h          13.3
#>  9 0610031O16Rik     9 GCN1-KO 0h          12.3
#> 10 0610031O16Rik    10 GCN1-KO 1h          25.3
#> # … with 1,202 more rows
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to format 500+ plots using facet wrap in R? \[images & code included\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64030818/best-way-to-format-500-plots-using-facet-wrap-in-r-images-code-included)

Comment: unfortunately not. When adding the `group_map` to the code I get the following error `Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: mgi_symbol. * Plot is missing mgi_symbol * Layer 1 is missing mgi_symbol`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with some dummy data. This is the data after you've finished running `left_join`, `pivot_longer`, `group_by`, `summarize`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  time = 1:5,
  mean_count = 1:5,
  cond = "x"
) %>%
  expand_grid(mgi_symbol = c(letters, LETTERS))
```

Create a column `group` which represents what page the `mgi_symbol` belongs on.

```
plots_per_page <- 20

df <-
  df %>%
  mutate(group = (dense_rank(mgi_symbol) - 1) %/% plots_per_page)
```

Create all the plots with `group_map`.

```
plots <- 
  df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  group_map(function(g, ...) {
    ggplot(g, aes(x = time, y = mean_count, fill=cond)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width=0.9) ) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkblue", "lightblue", "black")) +
      facet_wrap(~mgi_symbol, scales = "free", ncol = 5) +
      theme_bw()
  })
```

[Save as multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49707867/1751961) using `ggpubr`

```
ggpubr::ggexport(
  ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = plots, nrow = 1, ncol = 1),
  filename = "plots.pdf"
)
```

[image: pdf]

Comment: This is not working, as the data I'm basing my plots on are the `mgi_symbols`. I have added the top part of my data table to the question

Comment: I've edited your last cell to create `df` which matches mine. I just added an `ungroup`. You should be able to run my code from the second cell onwards.

Comment: Thanks a lot +5, if possible. Great solution.